# MATLAB - How to calculate 2D least squares regression based on both x and y. (regression surface)

Tags: matlab, statistics, regression

I have a set of data with independent variable x and y. Now I'm trying to build a two dimensional regression model that has a regression surface cutting through my data points. However, I couldn't find a way to achieve this. Can anyone give me some assistance?

Comment: Do you have the [Curve Fitting Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/curvefitting/) installed?

Answer (score 1):

You could use my favorite, [polyfitn](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34765-polyfitn) for linear or polynomial models.  If you would like a different model, please edit your question or add a comment.  HTH!

**EDIT**

Also, take a look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/programmatic-fitting.html?s_tid=doc_12b) under Multiple Regression, likely can help you as well.

**EDIT AGAIN**

Sorry, I'm having too much fun with this, here's an example of multivariate regression using least squares with *stock* Matlab:

```
t = (1:10)';
x = t;
y = exp(-t);
A = [ y x ];
z = 10*y + 0.5*x;
A\z
ans =

   10.0000
    0.5000
```

Comment: Ok, polyfitn is my fav too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are performing linear regression, the best tool is the `regress` function. Note that, if you are fitting a model of the form `y(x1,x2) = b1.f(x1) + b2.g(x2) + b3` this is still a linear regression, as long as you know the functions `f` and `g`.

```
Nsamp = 100;  %number of samples
X1 = randn(Nsamp,1);  %regressor 1 (could also be some computed f(x1) )
X2 = randn(Nsamp,1);  %regressor 2 (could also be some computed g(x2) )
Y  = X1 + X2 + randn(Nsamp,1);  %generate some data to be regressed

%now run the regression
[b,bint,r,rint,stats] = regress(Y,[X1 X2 ones(Nsamp,1)]);

% 'b' contains the coefficients, b1,b2,b3 of the fit; can be used to plot regression surface)
% 'r' contains residuals of the fit
% 'stats' contains the overall regression R^2, F stat, p-value and error variance
```